# To get the latest data from mysql

Tags: mysql, record

```
2023-11-16 12:27:21.677826
2023-11-16 12:27:21.832048
2023-11-16 12:27:21.978845
2023-11-16 12:27:22.010928
2023-11-16 12:27:22.037900
2023-11-16 12:33:31.663295
2023-11-16 12:33:31.685133
2023-11-16 12:33:31.706968
2023-11-16 12:33:31.728155
2023-11-16 12:33:31.752384
2023-11-16 12:33:31.777117
```

Hello everyone,

Please help me in finding the latest record from the above given timestamps.

I have tried using this query :

```
select data 
from table 
where column name > CURRENT_TIME
```

but by using this I get all the data as shown in above. but I need the latest records according to timestamps like I need data from this

```
timestamp
2023-11-16 12:33:31.663295
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL MAX() function to determine the latest record:

```
SELECT MAX(data) FROM table
```

If you wish to have multiple records just ordered by the datetime, this should do the trick

```
SELECT data FROM table ORDER BY column_name DESC
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried it earlier but it didnt work it gave me all the records as above.

Comment: Hi @shashankBharadwaj - did you try the query with MAX() function? It should give you only one result. If it doesn't, could you please provide me with example output.